# Cbpro issues, invalid price

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I'm using the following function from cbpro in order to buy some ETH. The dictionary returned is:

```
auth_client.buy(price='400', size = '0.00001', order_type = "market", product_id = currency)
```

{'message': 'Invalid price 400'}

Is the package broken or am I just being sutpid? Also tried in the form 400.00 but also not working.

Comment: maybe remove apostrophes from 400

Comment: On the documentation it's in strings

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#place-a-new-order) suggests that `price` is a floating-point number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No that doesn't work either.